# File won't open for writing

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to write contents of datastructure to a file but for some reason file.is_open() returns false. Am I missing something? Printing should work fine as I tested it with cout.

```
std::ofstream file;

file.open(filename, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {

    Candy* tmp = index[i];
    for(; tmp; tmp = tmp->next){
        if(file.is_open()){
            file << tmp->ID << ";" << tmp->amount << ";" << tmp->location <<
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: You only need to check the file is open once. Not every time.

Comment: Does it work *at all*, then stop? Properly indented, it appears that you're closing the file at the end of your outer `for` loop, so  when `i == 1`, etc. the file will definitely be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your curly braces are mismatched?
You never close out of the scope of the first for loop, so you are closing the file on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yea I moved the .close() out of the loop and it works now! I guess you become blind to your own code when u look at it for too long :D. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct permissions to write to the file path? Do the does the path to the file actually exist?

You can check the errno to find out what went wrong.

```
#include <cerrno>

std::cout << "File error: " << strerror( errno ) << std::endl;
```